# html css при скролле ресайз картинки

Tags: html, css, responsive, resize

Добрый день. Не могу разобраться в чём причина, может поможете? Вот сайт:
http://ipass.com.ua/ 
В шапке есть картинка, при медленном скролле(так лучше видно) c ТЕЛЕФОНА И АЙПАДА. В шапке изображение изменяет размер, а в хромовском web inspector не видно. Самое забавное, что предыдущая картинка точно такого же размера в пикселях нечего не изменяла, а эта ресайзит. Вот пример кода :

```
.main_header_bg {
  background-image: url(asset-path('header_bg.jpg'));
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 718px;
}
.main_header_text {
   padding-top: 60px;
   font-size: 29px;
}
.main_header_text h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}
```